# Как проверить посетителя на уникальность?

Tags: php

Как проверить переход на уникальность, то есть не было ли перехода от этого посетителя ранее. Если не было - выполняем определенные действия.

ip - не вариант, он может меняться...

Comment: В общем случае - __никак__. Поставите куку - шибко умные сотрут. IP как вы говорили - не вариант. Хранить факт перехода в БД? Заставить регистрироваться? Выбирайте сами.

Comment: @u_mulder не ужели никак?

Comment: Уникальность кого/чего? Человека, компьютера, браузера?

Comment: @Эникейщик компьютера/браузера

Comment: Кука, [зомби-кука](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_cookie), получать данные о конфигурации и хранить в базе на сервере.

Comment: @Эникейщик а есть примерв реализации? покуда не совсем понял смысл

Answer (score 0):

Предложу посмотреть в сторону [browser fingerprint](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), но сделав параллельные проверки по IP, cookie